# Difference between CreateProcessAsUser() to CreateProcessWithTokenW()

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi, process

I'm trying to understand the **difference** between the 2 API calls specified in the title.
The only visible difference I've noticed when I tried to mess up with the functions my self was that the `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` function adds the process to an isolated job where `CreateProcessAsUserA()`s prcoess joins a big group consist of his parnet process, the process created by `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` and others. in addistion `CreateProcessAsUserA()` require additional privileges in order to succeed, compared with `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` function that could run with out them, according to MSDNs documentation the required privileges specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera are:

[image: MSDN CreateProcessAsUserA()]

Comment: may be this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427094/createprocessasuser-works-createprocesswithtokenw-does-not/38442543#38442543 can be interesting for you. and also this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226029/windows-create-a-process-in-session-0-using-createprocesswithtokenw/66226619#66226619

Answer (score 0):

CreateProcessAsUser has been around forever, CreateProcessWithToken was added in Server 2003.

CreateProcessWithToken can load the users profile and deals with the winsta0 windowstation and desktop for you. I believe CreateProcessWithToken requires the secondary logon service to be running.

They require different token permissions so you should probably fall back to the other function if the first fails...

Comment: @Andres for my understanding, In the 7th Edition of Windows Internals it actually shows that `CreateProcessWithTokenW` and `CreateProcessWithLogonW` calls the SecLogon.dll and than it calls the `CreateProcessAsUser` which finally calls the `NtCreateUserProcess`, but a direct call to `CreateProcessAsUser` don't, instead it calls the `CreateProcessInternal` before calling the `NtCreateUserProcess`. And I want to understand exactly the need for both of the functions and not just fall back to the other one when the first one fails...

Comment: *I believe CreateProcessAsUser requires the secondary logon service to be running* - this is not true. @teamshmot - *CreateProcessWithTokenW* do rpc call to another process and already inside service call `CreateProcessAsUser`. the `CreateProcessAsUser`  always execute inside current process

Comment: *I believe CreateProcessAsUser requires the secondary logon service to be running* - or sorry, probably you make typo - *I believe **CreateProcessWithToken** requires the secondary logon service to be running* - this is true. yes